# Is is possible with label that the text which we want to display it comes to top of the label?

Tags: iphone

Is is possible with label that the text which we want to display it comes to top of the label.
I want the text on the at the top of the Label then how is possible?

Comment: The text is displayed inside the label. If you need it displayed higher, move the label up. Also, you can not have superscripts in a UILabel. If you need more complicated formatting, you need to use HTML (in a UIWebView).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently yes, [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9184756)'s a thread discussing(and apparently solving the problem) how to do vertical text alignment in a UILabel, including text that starts on top of the label and proceeds to filling it as more lines are added.